# i use a variable to echo the different title of different pages but i got an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

[i got an error on using a variable ( $page_title ) for echo the page title but it does not work and show me an error ]
[here is the code of header.php file]

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="sodalitesolutions">
    <meta name="author" content="sodalitesolutions">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style/slider.css'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style/mystyle.css'); ?>">
</head>
```

[Error :: function: _error_handler]

Comment: What is the error? Have you declared `$page_title`?

Comment: public function contact(){

                $data['page_title'] = "Home | Main Page";
  $this->load->view('pageheader');
  $this->load->view('web_navigation');
  $this->load->view('slider');
  $this->load->view('pages/contact');
  $this->load->view('footer');
 }

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed use `echo $data['page_title'];`

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this :

```
$this->data['title'] = 'test';
$this->load->view('view_name',$this->data);
```

Comment: i try your code and this is works fine, i forget that $data['page_title'] = "Home | Main Page";

  $this->load->view('pageheader',$data);